# Reach ViewController Inside TabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I am trying to implement menu to my app. I have `TabBarViewController -> NavigationViewController -> ContentViewController`. When app starts I open HostViewController. And inside of HostViewController i have to use this code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let tabbarVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarViewController") as! TabBarViewController
contentList.append(tabbarVC as MenuItemContentViewController)
```

But MenuItemContentViewController only inherits UIViewController. So I cannot use this code with tabbar.

I tried

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let contentVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController
contentList.append(contentVC as MenuItemContentViewController)
```

But it adds contentViewController without tabbar.

Is anyone knows how can I add contentViewController with tabbar and navbar?

Thanks.

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-exploring-tab-bar-controller--cms-25470

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you want contentViewController embedded in tabbar with navigation bar. You need to push or addSubview to hostViewController on any event i.e "IBAction or button click"

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let tabbarVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarViewController") as! TabBarViewController
self.present(tabbarVC, animated: True){} //In HostViewController's Self
```

Or

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let tabbarVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarViewController") as! TabBarViewController 
self.view.addSubview(tabbarVC.view) //In HostViewController's Self
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the `UIViewController` Instance from `UITabBarController`
Using

```
tabbarVC.viewControllers[index] as! MenuItemContentViewController
```